# Get API key - Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, get, key

For the past couple of days we're trying to get an API key from Google Maps Javascript API, but we always end up to the link of creating a project. The problem is we can't create a project, we always get the error "Unknown error" in the notification panel. We're developing a web site that shows a map with location markers (pushpins). Locally works fine, but moving to the hosting server it stops working.

We do have Gmail accounts, business type, we would like to use the Standard Plan, what are the steps to get this API key ? Are we missing something ?

We do appreciate for any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello have you tried this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=fr

"Get a key", then register with your credit card and you done. The fees are applied when you up to 25k req/day or something like this.